# Search for Child Objects with No Child Objects

Tags: backendless

Backendless documentation has an [example](https://backendless.com/documentation/data/android/data_relations_retrieve.htm) about querying related objects;  **Phonebook** (parent) has child **Contact** (child) has child **Address** (grandchild) (phonebook->contact->address).

You can use "is null" to [find parent objects with no child object](http://support.backendless.com/topic/search-table-by-property-where-null)

```
Contact is null
```

But when you try to find child objects with no grandchild objects. The query fails with "invalid where clause."

```
Contact.Address is null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I developed this solution, which checks to see if the grandchild object system generated field is null.

```
Contact.Address.created is null //Contact has no Address child object

Contact.Address.created is not null //Contact has Address child object
```